# Add permission to two users (my apache server and myself)

Tags: linux, apache, terminal, permissions

I want my php script to be able to create file, edit, and delete it, so I need to give it permissions to do so in Linux. 
I've done this with one of the stackoverflow answers with this code:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

But when I do so, I lose my user access to files - so I can't open them with gedit for example until I change permissions back like so:

```
sudo chown -R igor  /var/www/html/demo/myDir
```

I think I need to give permission to Apache, but leave my access as well. I feel there is some easy answer to make it work, but I can't find one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the owner of the files, if you want to change the permission of the files without changing the owner you need to use : `chmod`.
For example if you want to read write and execute on the current folder you can use: `chmod 777 .`

If what you want is the two users have the same permissions over the folder you could add your user to the group `www-data` (assuming that you are in the files folder):

`sudo usermod -a -G www-data youruser
sudo chgrp -R www-data .
sudo chmod -R 770 .`

Comment: I've checked the groups for $user via terminal command "groups $user". I've added myself ot www-data: "$user : $user adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare". I still can't access file: Could not open the file “/var/www/html/demo/myDir/test2.txt”. When I try to access permissions of the file via UI, they are all grayed out. Most likely because $user still don't have access to file.

Comment: Here is what I get when I check file permission with ls - l "-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 51 окт.  23 23:11 /var/www/html/demo/myDir/test2.txt"

Comment: If it makes any difference, file I have problem with was created by PHP itself.